# Integrated Security Connection Issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, iis

I got an asp.net application that has been deployed to production. I'm using integrated security as part of my connection and it times out in production. The timeout is due to not being able to connect to the database. I get Login failed. I'm using Windows Authentication and we're using IIS6. However, from my development machine it runs great.

this is my connstring: add name="blah" connectionString"Data Source=serverName; Initial Catalog=Blah;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Any feedback is greatly appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Don't you mean `Integrated Security`?

Comment: Yes, Integrated Security. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check as which user the AppPool in IIS is running. That user needs permission in SQL server. I recommend to create a specific user for security reasons.